# Conditional rendering sidebar with Ant design error

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3, ant-design-vue, antdv

I'm using nuxt 3.7 with nuxt/ant-design-vue 4. Now I have a layout. I want it like this: if mobile, let the left sidebar show up; else, show the header. But there are some errors I don't know what they come from. Please help. Many thanks

This is the template.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sURVo.png)

And this is errors & warning
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KM4j3.png)

solve my bugs as fast as posible